# Conditional Formatting of Names Based on Matching Concatenated Name and Birthday in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to highlight students whose birthdays = TODAY across multiple sheets and am seeking some advice. In a sheet named **StudentInfo**, there are a number of columns: FirstName (B), LastName (C), **FullName** (D), Advisor (E), Locker (F), **Birthday** (G), etc. Col **FullName** is a concatenation of cols B and C, such as =C2 &", "&B2 (showing Lastname, Firstname). So, this is a calculated value instead of a string. Also, I've named the range in col FullName (D) as "**StudentList**" and the range in col Birthday (G) as "**Birthdays**."

In other sheets, I input student names using this same format: Lastname, Firstname (string value only, no concatenation). What I'd like to do is in these other sheets, have conditional formatting highlight the student name cells meeting the two conditions: cell = StudentInfo!StudentList AND Birthdays = TODAY. I can get conditional formatting for birthday reminders to work easy on the StudentInfo sheet, but am struggling with the conditional formatting logic to highlight student names in other sheets. Something like...
**=B4=StudentList AND DATEVALUE(TEXT(Birthdays,"m/d")=TODAY())**

Is it possible to use another sheet while conditional formatting in this way? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it would be a good idea, if you have not already done so, to make sure your birthdates use Excel's built-in dates (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEDrzcPo_mc if you need an introduction to what this means).

Next assuming that in your non-StudentInfo worksheets the names are in column `A`, the formula

`=MATCH(A5,StudentList,0)`

tells you the position within the range `Studentlist` of the student whose name is in cell `A5`.

Further, the birthdate of that student can be looked up in range `Birthdays` by using this position with the `INDEX` function. The formula for this is

`=INDEX(Birthdays,MATCH(A5,StudentList,0))`

You now want to know if the day-within-month number and the month number of this birthdate matches today's day-within-month number and today's month number.

Four functions which you will need for this are:

`TODAY()` provides today's date

`DAY(date)` provides the day-within-month number for the given `date`

`MONTH(date)` provides the month number for the given `date`

`AND(v1,v2)` provides the means of determining whether two boolean values `v1` and `v2` are both `TRUE` (a boolean is a value which is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`). The result is `TRUE` if and only if both `v1` and `v2` are `TRUE`, otherwise it is `FALSE`.

The match between the day-within-month numbers of the birthdate and today is determined by the formula

`=DAY(INDEX(Birthdays,MATCH(A5,Studentlist,0)))=DAY(TODAY())`

and this takes the value `TRUE` if the two day-within-month numbers match and `FALSE` if they are different.

Similarly, the match between the month numbers for the birthdate and today is determined by the formula

`=MONTH(INDEX(Birthdays,MATCH(A5,StudentList,0)))=MONTH(TODAY())`

Both the day-within-month number and month number expressions are booleans and can be wrapped inside an `AND` to give the formula

`=AND(DAY(INDEX(Birthdays,MATCH(A5,StudentList,0)))=DAY(TODAY()),MONTH(INDEX(Birthdays,MATCH(A5,StudentList,0)))=MONTH(TODAY()))`

and this is `TRUE` if the birthday (of the student's birthdate) occurs today and `FALSE` otherwise.

This latter formula is the one you should apply in the conditional formatting rule for cell `A5`.

**Notes**

1. The formula should be applied to the first cell in each non-StudentInfo worksheet containing a student's name. I have assumed this is cell `A5`. If it is a different cell then replace the two occurrences of `A5` in the formula with with appropriate cell value.
2. Use the format painter to copy this first cell's format to the remaining cells in the worksheet which have student names.
3. It would be a good idea to test whether the names on each of the non-StudentInfo  worksheets match the "master" list in `StudentList`. To do this in a convenient empty column put the formula

`=MATCH(A5,StudentList,0)`

(substituting the appropriate cell reference for `A5` and copy this cell down to for the remaining names).

Any mismatches will show up as `#N/A` errors. You should compare any names showing this error with the corresponding name in `StudentList` and make any correction necessary to eliminate the error.

4. If you just enter the dates into range `Birthdays` using a 'd/m' format (or 'm/d' if that is your locale) Excel will probably convert this to a date in the current year. This does not matter for the purposes of determing which birthdays occur today, since you are only looking at day-within-month and month numbers. However, it might matter if you want to calculate the age in years of the students. Something to be aware of (possibly).

Comment: THANK YOU DMM for your time and detail describing this. It works perfectly!!!!!